# How do I echo a mixture of php and html in php?

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a loop and each time the loop runs, I want it to echo a new div inside which there is a php variable. Here's my code at the moment:

```
<?php

$i = 1;
while($i <= 5){
    echo "<div class=\"box\"><p>"$confessions[$i]"</p></div>"
    $i++;
}

?>
```

However, this isn't working. What's the correct way to do something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't it working? have you assigned class `box` to any value?

Comment: Nope, box is just a css class I made. Any other ideas?

Comment: why just not use single quotes inside the double ?

Comment: in your case:
`echo "<div class=\"box\"><p>"{$confessions[$i]}"</p></div>"`
read from here(http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) to the end of document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. You have to sort of put an "and" between html and php in php/html echoes. That "and" is "." You also have to end the line with a comment.

Solution:

```
echo '<div class="box"><p>' . $confessions[$i] . '</p></div>';
```

Comment: Remember, echo is NOT a PHP function, but a language construct. The ('s are unnecessary and misleading. You can't do `$var = 'echo'; $$var("value");`

Comment: Note that `echo` is not a function and therefore does not require the parentheses.

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to concatenate the parts together:

```
 echo "<div class=\"box\"><p>".$confessions[$i]."</p></div>";
```

Notice where I placed the dot operators (.), also end the line with a semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

[*"When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it"*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), so if you're going to use double quotes, you could also do it like this:

```
echo "<div class='box'><p>{$confessions[$i]}</p></div>";
```

*(For readability, I changed your HTML attributes to use single quotes. The HTML spec allows either.)*

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way:

```
echo '<div class="box"><p>' . $confessions[$i] . '</p></div>';
```

- you have to use "." to concatenate (connect) strings
- always end your commands with a semi-colon ;)
- when you use ' instead of ", you don't have to escape your HTML-"
- using ' is actually being processed faster by PHP than using "
- if you are using an IDE with syntax highlighting, it displays the variable in a different colour than your HTML

Comment: The speed difference between using single or double quotes is irrelevant. Always go for readability over speed.

Comment: Always is a hard word, though I find this one more readable because of syntax highlighting. Good point ;)

Comment: I believe that it is noticeable for large amounts of text...

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse, that depends on what you mean by "noticeable". We're talking about microsecond differences here even for doing thousands of iterations.

Comment: Hmm it appears that it may even be 0: http://phpbench.com/

Answer (score 1):

Missing the '.'s and ';' - should be getting parse errors if you have error reporting and display_errors on.

```
echo "<div class=\"box\"><p>".$confessions[$i]."</p></div>";
```

Comment: `echo "<div class=\"box\"><p>".$confessions[$i]."</p></div>";`
You're wrong.... that's the right way to do it

Comment: Woops, typo'd. How embarrasing. Thanks guys.